# Accessing php object's property (not working)

Tags: php, object

I have a PHP object **$resp** with this structure (printed to Chrome's console via a JS hack(*)):

```
Object {data: Array[25], paging: Object}
  data: Array[25]
    0: ... # NOT empty
```

When I try to do:

```
$elements = $resp->data;
print_r($elements);
foreach ($elements as $key => $element) {
     // handle array's element here...
}
```

I get:

- **print_r**: prints **nothing**
- **forloop** is **never executed** (I tried **error_log('loop')** within the loop)

What am I doing wrong? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what the actual output is (since I print it to console via the JS hack)?

I also tried

```
$elements = $resp['data'];
echo($elements);
```

but I get

> {{

printed to my page (in the browser).

(*)

```
console.log(<?php echo $resp;?>);
```

Comment: You can't do this `console.log(<?php echo $resp2;?>);`

Comment: Make sure you're looking at the page source and not the parsed HTML.

Comment: Also, it is often better to use `var_dump` instead of `print_r` since `print_r` does not output anything for boolean `false` or `null` values.

Comment: @aldrin27 It depends on what `$resp2` is. If it's just a string, there's nothing wrong with that, as long as it's wrapped in a `<script>` tag (in the sense that it would work). However it is pretty pointless as it's much easier to just look at the page's source code.

Comment: @Mike can you please be more precise, with an example? (feel free to answer instead of comment)

Comment: never mind. I found out the issue (will post the solution as answer) @Mike thanks for the var_dump advice, it helped!

Comment: Don't use Javascript to debug PHP; that's about three layers removed and can introduce any number of issues in-between which skew the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike's comment helped.

In fact $resp (returned by a GET call) was a **string**.

I converted it to object by:

> json_decode($resp)

and

> var_dump($resp->data)

gave me the expected result (i.e. the object 'data' in string form)